# Frequency that elements appear in an array. Code works but looking for a better answer

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, lambda, count

I'm looking for a more efficient and easier way to count the number of elements in an array and how frequently they appear.  GroupBy is the obvious answer but then I'd like to generate a result that's the same dimensions as the original array.

I'm writing this in C# and want to leverage lambda expressions.  My code works but there has to be a better way to do something this simple.

```
        var testarray = new int[10]
        { 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 5 };


        var groups = testarray.GroupBy(p => p)
            .Select(group => new
            {
                TestKey = group.Key,
                Count = group.Count()
            });

        var final = testarray.Join(groups,
            src => src,
            dest => dest.TestKey,
            (src, dest) => dest.Count
            ).ToArray();
```

Input:
`{ 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 5 }`

Expected and actual results:
`{3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2}`

Comment: Up-vote for showing effort and example input/output. In relation to your question - you'd have to be a bit clearer in how you want this improved, since I think it's 'fine' (in terms of general approach) the way it is. If it's a working version and you're open to any suggestion, it might be that http://codereview.stackexchange.com is the best place for it.

Comment: Group and count *are* the better answer if you want the frequency. What you ask though is to get a *second* array that repeats each value's frequency, like SQL's` `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION by SomeColumn)`

Comment: "generate a result that's the same dimensions as the original array"... what about {99, 3, 6, 9, 99}? Would that return an array with the 100 elements, since a[99] would be 2?

Comment: @AKX sorry for the ambiguity.  For your example, I'd like the code to return {2, 1, 1, 1, 2}

Comment: Make `groups` a dictionary of `item -> count` with `testarray.GruopBy(p => p).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())` then `final = testarray.Select(i => groups[i]).ToArray()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `GroupBy` to group the items store the counts in a `Dictionary`, then construct the final array by looking up each element in the dictionary to retrieve its count.

```
var testarray = new int[10] { 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 5 };
var dict = testarray.GroupBy(item => item).ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Count());
var final = testarray.Select(item => dict[item]).ToArray();
```

testarray
 `3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 5`

final
 `3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2`

Answer (score 0):

Executing `GroupBy` effectively creates an internal `Dictionary` (actually, a `Lookup`) and then you are breaking it back down in order to create the final `Dictionary`.

That seems wasteful to me. It may be more efficient to use `ToLookup`, which returns the `Lookup`, and then get the counts:

```
var counts = testarray.ToLookup(n => n);
var final = testarray.Select(t => ((ICollection<int>)counts[t]).Count).ToArray();
```